# TinyMCE editor unclickable / disabled in Codeigniter 4

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, tinymce

I'm working on converting my website from Codeigniter 3 to 4.  I'm planning to upgrade TinyMCE after the Codeigniter upgrade is finished, but currently am on TinyMCE version 4.1.7

After converting my pages to CodeIgniter 4 the TinyMCE editors are rendering but I can't click into them.  There are no errors showing in the console. I tried removing all plugins but have the same behavior.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

```
<br/><label>News*</label><textarea name="fldNews" cols="40" rows="10" id="fldNews" placeholder="News content" maxlength="10000" type="textarea"></textarea>
<br/><label>Quote</label><textarea name="fldQuote" cols="40" rows="10" id="fldQuote" placeholder="Quote" maxlength="250" type="textarea"></textarea>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            statusbar:false,
            height: 450,
            relative_urls:false,
            browser_spellcheck:true,
            content_css:'<?php echo base_url("css/desktop.css")?>',
            plugins: [
                "link image",
                "code fullscreen",
                "table contextmenu",
                "paste",
                "image",
                "caption"
            ],
            menubar:true,
            toolbar: "bold italic underline strikethrough | fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect | paste | bullist numlist | outdent indent | blockquote | removeformat | image caption | code",
            file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {

                tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                    file : '<?php echo base_url("manage/files")?>',
                    title : 'My File Browser',
                    width : 820,  
                    height : 400,
                    resizable : "yes",
                    inline : "yes",  
                    close_previous : "no"
                }, {
                    window : win,
                    input : field_name
                });
                // if(type=='image') $('#image-upload-input').data("id",field_name).show().click().hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: what version of CI4 are you using? Asking because of this: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_432.html#base-url. Anyway you should be able to see the url in your browser network tab

Comment: @Vickel We are on CI 4.4.1. Also, the TinyMCE editor rendors, so it seems to be importing fine...the editor is just frozen/not clickable

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this- I cleared my browser cache and it started working again!